# Disable output caching on individual web part (MOSS 2007)

Tags: asp.net, caching, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

We run our external website on Sharepoint 2007, and all the content is pulled from list data and generated using C# web parts.

Here is my problem: I have a web part on the home page that displays a random header banner on every page load.  Unfortunately, Sharepoint seems to be caching this header and showing the same image every time, rather than randomizing it.  I know this because the web part works properly for logged in users, and we've told SP to disable output caching for logged in users.

I would like to keep output caching enabled for anonymous users, but somehow tell sharepoint not to cache this particular web part.  I know there's a way to do this, but it seems like there are so many different ways to approach caching and I don't know which one will work.  I should note, I've tried using the PartCacheInvalidate method within the web part code, with no luck.  Any ideas?